# Concise way to enumerate nested comprehension

Tags: python

What's the best way to do an enumeration for a nested comprehension?  That is, I want `i` to be successively the values, `0`, `1`, ..., until it gets to `len(my_x_list) * len(my_y_list) - 1` in the following:

```py
my_list = [my_function(i, x, y) for x in my_x_list for y in my_y_list]
```

I can do it with a comprehension inside a comprehension, as follows, but I am hoping for something that uses a single nested comprehension.

```py
my_list = [
    my_function(i, x, y)
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(((x, y) for x in my_x_list for y in my_y_list))
]
```

I can do it with some index arithmetic, as follows, but that too seems a bit ugly, and it gets pretty tricky when `my_y_list` is replaced by something that depends upon `x` and has a length that depends upon `x`.

```py
len_y_list = len(my_y_list)
my_list = [
    my_function(m * len_y_list + n, x, y)
    for m, x in enumerate(my_x_list)
    for n, y in enumerate(my_y_list)
]
```

Is there an approach that uses a single comprehension and a single call to `enumerate()`?

Comment: "gets pretty tricky when my_y_list is replaced by something that depends upon x and has a length that depends upon x." I highly doubt you can do that without an extra comprehension (or at least an equivalent like a utility function running the comprehension or enumerate for you), since that is exactly what your requirement implies in the general case. *Why* are you trying to avoid the extra comprehension? Is your goal merely to write this shorter and not necessarily more efficiently?

Comment: "Why are you trying to avoid the extra comprehension":  For efficiency.  If having two comprehensions is just as efficient then that would be good enough.  (Unless there is a single comprehension approach that works too, which might then win out on readability.)

Comment: If this is about efficiency... How long are your lists, so that we can benchmark accordingly?

Comment: My lists are about 1000 entries each in my test case.  Ultimately they could be 10K each.

Comment: Ok, added that to my benchmark results. As expected, relative speeds are very similar with my original length 300 and length 1000.

Answer (score 3):

Two fast solutions and benchmarks.

#### Solution 1

Using `enumerate` on the inner `for` clause, continuing with the next number. Not a single *call* to `enumerate`, but a single occurrence in the code, and still efficient:

```
my_list = [
    my_function(i, x, y)
    for i in [-1]
    for x in my_x_list
    for i, y in enumerate(my_y_list, i+1)
]
```

#### Solution 2

Not a list comprehension but faster, using `count`/`repeat` from `itertools`:

```
my_list = []
i = count(1)
for x in my_x_list:
    i = count(next(i) - 1)
    my_list += map(my_function, i, repeat(x), my_y_list)
```

#### Benchmarks

With two lists of length 300 and a do-nothing function:

```
   8.9 ±  0.1 ms  Kelly_2
  11.9 ±  0.1 ms  Kelly_1
  12.4 ±  0.1 ms  MisterMiyagi_1
  15.0 ±  0.3 ms  MisterMiyagi_2
  15.6 ±  0.1 ms  Xnot
  17.3 ±  0.3 ms  original_2
  19.9 ±  0.4 ms  original_1

sys.version = '3.10.6 (main, Jan  7 2023, 10:15:17) [GCC 12.2.0]'
```

With lists of length 1000 as you commented:

```
 102.1 ±  1.3 ms  Kelly_2
 134.6 ±  0.9 ms  Kelly_1
 142.3 ±  2.4 ms  MisterMiyagi_1
 169.6 ±  0.9 ms  MisterMiyagi_2
 176.0 ±  2.4 ms  Xnot
 194.6 ±  1.2 ms  original_2
 219.4 ±  3.4 ms  original_1
```

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=vVbNjtMwEL6ivAS-xe6mVbvLIhSpB-CIljNSqSKzdYpF4kS2s0pU9Um47AXuvAKPwdMw_knq7GbFLhLk5HyezHzfNxMnX7_Xnf5cidvbb43O569-PXu-Yzl6x4qiy1a47LK8EdeaVyJBcNNmBVfaLju7JGmE4JJMN1Kgjb0xV_Ag5glqE9SRYTOvJOKIQ_x8tR2hrUGHOuMHIIXZZaIpmaSa4YFEgvjZyqXfRtGJ__kT-Kum0GiNNo4Ph-V11QiNfd775NKB3SlYsFZjTtAcrU5qfe6zNSppPWYEmiSrGdW4JSGp0FP3uJNVSb7nghb_tjMJwhYdu409eN8JC3Ue8sVH3RhoP74hBRMeAHPhBk-bMy2rRLMwwRkSUzrLxOkYDVQb1OgDxcOTN5J5BQCTV7yje_6EDpnxma9GqkIxmKdrM95ewuP8n2L0ePNPA00epOVH_W9YfRCV_v_zy8EJXVWFWtSy2jXXGk9WHTpqiigwwh-FSX-mJMFbGKwBH_f_zj3sG92QV1Yl0rxkiJd1JTWqmcwzazeTiCq756KUphpycODhY0tGwS6ld-zGhQyq-gibqD9WIg8OUT2gOhVFVO6NQOxeOFp-2lHkHU1RHh_4MT20x0N3jBMXAlxw_PrN25iEQNvFJCKRsT43llvjXPNqyWGIZjmemVowLPkiywQtWZaRP9R_XwkWVJFU7Bm-WC4JmUaBgTHOJDzkKZzjaEzoaEfPOKpw7mdLm-iNhtNixS5svDbxChxiO2zTbfIt2aSX2204jOCNaQTWiqQvF6v8iH7-QAfbFYu9sFipUBwNnzpH9fzSl55yy1JaAiVTGQdD7e07BXlmC1rXTDim2Hx19DLog5dhCyToC-vWVj0JW9P7caczbjOPP4oDTMrihkkFrxswO8bE_Sf434X-t-E3)):

```py
def Kelly_1(my_function, my_x_list, my_y_list):
    return [
        my_function(i, x, y)
        for i in [-1]
        for x in my_x_list
        for i, y in enumerate(my_y_list, i+1)
    ]

def Kelly_2(my_function, my_x_list, my_y_list):
    result = []
    i = count(1)
    for x in my_x_list:
        i = count(next(i) - 1)
        result += map(my_function, i, repeat(x), my_y_list)
    return result

def original_1(my_function, my_x_list, my_y_list):
    return [
        my_function(i, x, y)
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(((x, y) for x in my_x_list for y in my_y_list))
    ]

def original_2(my_function, my_x_list, my_y_list):
    len_y_list = len(my_y_list)
    return [
        my_function(m * len_y_list + n, x, y)
        for m, x in enumerate(my_x_list)
        for n, y in enumerate(my_y_list)
    ]

def MisterMiyagi_1(my_function, my_x_list, my_y_list):
    i = -1
    return [my_function((i:=i+1), x, y) for x in my_x_list for y in my_y_list]

def MisterMiyagi_2(my_function, my_x_list, my_y_list):
    i = count()
    return [my_function(next(i), x, y) for x in my_x_list for y in my_y_list]

def Xnot(my_function, my_x_list, my_y_list):
    return [
        my_function(i, x, y)
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.product(my_x_list, my_y_list))
    ]

funcs = Kelly_1, Kelly_2, original_1, original_2, MisterMiyagi_1, MisterMiyagi_2, Xnot

from time import perf_counter as time
from statistics import mean, stdev
from itertools import count, repeat
import itertools
import sys

args = (
    lambda i, x, y: f'{i}:{x}{y}',
    list('ABC'),
    list('xy')
)
for f in funcs:
    print(*f(*args), f.__name__)

args = (
    lambda i, x, y: None,
    list(range(300)),
    list(range(300))
)
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.1f} ± {stdev(ts):4.1f} ms '
for i in range(25):
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        f(*args)
        times[f].append(time() - t0)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print(f'\n{sys.version = }')
```

Comment: I this one too, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for Solution 2.  It is odd that `i = count(next(i) - 1)` is required.  Do you suppose that this a bug or feature of `map()`?

Comment: @Lee That's normal/expected. The `map` iterator reads values from its three input iterables `i`, `repeat(x)` and `my_y_list`. It stops when one of them doesn't have another value. The first two are infinite, so it stops when `my_y_list` doesn't have another value. But when `map` realizes that, it has already read the next value from `i` (and from `repeat(x)`).  So I need to go one step back for the next round.

Answer (score 2):

Simply perform the counting manually:

```
i = -1
my_list = [my_function((i:=i+1), x, y) for x in my_x_list for y in my_y_list]
```

Alternatively, use an `itertools.count` or similar to perform the counting.

```
from itertools import count

i = count()
my_list = [my_function(next(i), x, y) for x in my_x_list for y in my_y_list]
```

Comment: I like this!  It is unfortunate that the walrus operator := isn't available until Python 3.8, which may be a problem for others but is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

my_list = [
    my_function(i, x, y)
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.product(my_x_list, my_y_list))
]
```

Answer (score -2):

`itertools.product` will be great as long as your inputs are small.

I would use numpy and a [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to imitate the behavior of the nested list comprehension. The nice thing is that we can use it to create an array of any dimension, which is cleaner than nesting more and more lists.

```
import numpy as np

x_data = [11, 22, 33]
y_data = [444, 555, 666, 777]
x_data, y_data = (array.ravel() for array in np.meshgrid(x_data, y_data))
indices = np.arange(x_data.size) # Similar to `range(len(x_data) * len(y_data))`

# x_data
# [11, 22, 33, 11, 22, 33, 11, 22, 33, 11, 22, 33]
# y_data
# [444, 555, 666, 777, 444, 555, 666, 777, 444, 555, 666, 777]
# indices
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

for i, x, y in zip(indices, x_data, y_data):
    function(i, x, y)
```

If you tell us more about the `function` we can probably get rid of the loop entirely and squeeze the code for more performance.